# How to write a convex combination in terms of optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $w$, $s$ and $y$ be vectors in $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in [0,1]$. The convex combination of $w$ and $s$ are as follows

$$
y = (1-t)w + ts \tag{1}
$$

Consider the following optimization problem:
$$ 
y_* = \arg\min_{y \in C} -t\langle y,s -w \rangle + \frac{1}{2} \|y - w\|_2^2 \tag{2} 
$$

which can be solved to get $y_*$ because the objective, i.e.,  $f(y) = -t\langle y,s -w\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \|y - w\|_2^2$ is convex, so the necessary and sufficient condition in order $y_*$ be the minimizer of $(2)$ is the following:

$$ 
\langle -t (s -w) +  (y-w), y- y_* \rangle \geq 0 \,\,\,\, \forall y \in C
$$

$$ 
\langle y - ((1-t)w +t s) , y - y_*  \rangle \geq 0 \,\,\,\, \forall y \in C
\tag{3}$$

Evidently, for $y_* = (1-t)w +t s$ $(3)$ holds true not only for all $y \in C$ but also for every $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, the cost function is strongly convex so it is strictly convex, therefore, it has one global minimizer.

Question:
Using $(3)$ how can we prove that, $y_*$ is indeed $(1-t)w +t s$?

Comment: Do you know that $y_* \in C$? If not, it isn't feasible to (2), so your claim doesn't hold. If so, then $y_*$ is an unconstrained minimizer of the objective of (2) and therefore must be a (constrained) minimizer of (2) as well.

Comment: @madnessweasley: $y_*$ is the minimizer of $(2)$ and has to be in $C$ because the optimization is over $C$. My questions is why choosing $y_*=(1-t)w+ts$ which is a point in $C$ is the minimizer of constraint problem. In other words, assume we just had $(3)$, can we think of other $y \in C$ for which $(3)$ holds?

Comment: @LinAlg: I have marked all the ones that has been answered. If I have forgotten one and you aware of that, please let me know.

Comment: @LinAlg: Dear LinAlg, there are several questions on the statement that are left unanswered :-). Your answer addressed just 2 of them but it was helpful and gave me insight. I marked it off.

Comment: Do you need to use (3)? Why not use the first order criterion?

Comment: @LinAlg: my confusion is why for the special choice of $y=(1-t)w+ts$ for $(3)$ works well which I think because it is the unconstrained solution of the problem no matter what $C$  is. However, I was wondering if there are other $y$'s that can satisfy $(3)$ which I think depends on the constraint set.

Comment: I see. Then I do not understand the question. If $(1-t)w+ts) \in C$ and if $y_*=(1-t)w+ts)$ satisfies (3), then $y_*$ is the global miniimizer, so it is also the miniimizer when you minimize over $C$.